# sql query - timeline chart depending on start / endtime

Tags: mysql

i hope to get help for creating a query for a chart!

my table has following fields

```
userid
videoname
starttime
endtime
```

what I need is a chart where the numbers of users are listed in 12 parts (videolength / 12)

```
videolength = max(endtime)-min(starttime)
```

The x axis should have 12 parts e.g. 12 minutes video  has 12 parts, 1 each. 24 minutes video has also 12 parts, 2 each.

The chart should tell how many users we have in the first 1/12, 2/12, 3/12 etc... all depends on the start/endtime, as a user could start and end in the first 1/12.

I hope my description was enough to understand!? :-)

many thanks
Eder

Comment: x achse? Is that 'x-axis'?

Comment: Lucky that SO has an edit button then. :-)